# Background image on child divtags on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css

I  got a question on the below html code for the chrome and firefox.

```
<div id="div1" align="left" style="width: 500px; height: 40px; color: grey; background-image: url("bgmageurl"); font-size: 20px; font-style: italic;"> <
div id="divContent" align="left" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: grey; background-image: inherit;"> </div>
 <div id="divButton" align="right" style="background-image: inherit; "> </div> 
</div>
```

I am trying to have same  bg image displayed over to the  child  . That is why I tried using the inherit. But inherit just reshow the image all again, which I dont want. I want the same parent image to be stretched to the child div tag as well. I am not able to find a way .any thoughts? Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: <div id="div1" align="left" style="width: 500px; height: 40px; color: grey; background-image: url("bgmageurl"); font-size: 20px; font-style: italic;">


 <div id="divContent" align="left" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: grey; background-image: inherit;">
 </div>
 <div id="divButton" align="right" style="background-image: inherit; ">

 </div>
</div>

Comment: There's no such thing as `background-image: inherit;` in css. If your image doesn't show up make sure the url is right.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Below is code. I am not getting why the parent tag's bg image is not copied/stretched to the child in chrome and firefox. In Ie it works fine.

Comment: I am not able to copy it fully as the it exceeds the timit. Let me try to trim it a little bit

Comment: <html>
<div align="left" id="div1" style="width: 500px; height: 40px; color: grey;
background-image: url(&quot;http://static.myopera.com/community/graphics/speeddials/Opera-Background-Blue-Swirls.jpg&quot;);
font-size: 20px; font-style: italic;">
<div align="left" style=" background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100px; height: 38px;" >
</div>
<div align="left" id="divContent" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: grey; ">
te</div>
</div>
</html>

Comment: U can see the difference in IE and chrome

Comment: Get rid of the `""` in the `url()` declaration for the image and try again, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

The height on div1 (40px) seems to be the problem, divContent lies outside since the first child is allready 38px high. If you set height to auto, divContent also gets the background.

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/QMkfW/2/